# WebBrowser not responding to Up arrow key?

Tags: wpf, browser, tabcontrol

In a WPF application, I am hosting a WebBrowser control within a TabControl.

I have noticed that when a page is loaded in the browser I can navigate the page using many of the expected keys (down arrow, left arrow, right arrow, page up and page down etc).

However, when I click the up arrow, the page does not move up by a line, but instead selects the first tab in the tab control.

Anyone know what is happening here and how to go about fixing it?

Comment: Using snoop I have discovered that the keydown is handled by the webbrowser, but the keyup is handled by the tab item. But I can't figure out why.